Seed phrase compromised, ERC20/NFT remaining, what are the options?
This is general Q&A for all the "My wallet is compromised by a sweeper bot, what can I do?" questions, as well as an attempt to combat the "Crypto Theft Recovery Options" questions that are really scam product placements.
It also hopes to prevent users missing useful information by either being ignored or redirected as a hopeless case, when they could potentially be able to recover some funds.
Example of the former:


My Coinbase Wallet Seedphrase is compromised

Example of the latter:


https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/162654/recover-stolen-assets-crypto-theft-recovery-options
(likley removed)

Example of a user having funds rescued when pointed in the right direction:


My Coinbase Wallet Seedphrase is compromised


Uses and limitations
If your seed phrase has been compromised, and you fear or are aware of, a sweeper bot tracking your wallet (automated script that will take or use any eth you send, to steal any remaining tokens), it can still be possible to rescue remaining assets.
The whitehats cannot rescue tokens that have already been stolen.

NOTE It is important to verify the links and information in these posts, as well as to never blindly trust anyone who says they can help you recover funds


What can be done?
Using a second EOA, custom contracts that perform the operations involved atomically, gasless transaction methods that allow to pay for the transaction costs at the end of the process (or at least without the compromised wallet having to be funded), it is possible to recover NFT's, LP positions, tokens with a future unlock date etc.
You can perform a rescue if you work through the process of setting up the scripts/contracts and using the correct endpoints/parameters etc, if technically minded that might be a route to explore.
If inexperienced or just not confident in getting it right at a critical moment, there is a group with a proven track record of assisting in these cases.
Flashbots are well funded, well respected, with a dedicated support team.
If the amount of crypto at risk has a value of $1000 or greater and is on Ethereum (potentially Solana/BSC), then you can contact Flashbots rescue service, and their whitehats may be able to set up rescues for those assets.
This includes tokens that are stuck through lack of gas fees but available to move now, as well as for tokens that might require unstaking or have yet to be unlocked. They can set up rescues for the days the tokens will launch and attempt to front run the scammers in withdrawing.

NOTE It is important to verify the links and information in these posts, as well as to never blindly trust anyone who says they can help you recover funds


Where to find a whitehat?
You can find the flashbots rescue team on their discord.

link from the website:


https://discord.com/invite/7hvTycdNcK





https://www.flashbots.net/




https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/other-resources



View the channel: #⛑whitehat-token-rescue-service for more information.

NOTE If you have filled out the form and are unsure it has been recorded or are concerned about time sensitivity. It can be of value to message someone with the serv.eth role in #general just to confirm it has been received and that your user name is in the list.
It is not guaranteed that someone will be available to take a case.

