How can i claim airdrop from contract with another wallet not whitelisted
i have an airdrop wallet to claim DOP token on erc20 which cant be transfer yet on chain, but the wallet is compromised, i need a way out

Hey someone has voted to close this question, but you may still be able to save those tokens. Please see the answer here (while bein very careful of people claiming that they can help): https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/162661/seed-phrase-compromised-erc20-nft-remaining-what-are-the-options
