CLAIMING MY RETIK TOKENS IF MY META MASK WALLET IS COMPROMISED?
During the presale of Retik I bought 5682 tokens. When it came time to claim Retik only allowed 5% a week for 20 weeks to be claimed. I had purchased Retik and linked my Meta Mask wallet to Retik to claim my tokens when the time came. I was able to claim 277 tokens the first time and send it to my Uniswap account with no issue. When I went to claim the second week I noticed every stage I went to claim, and when my tokens went into Meta Mask, within seconds my eutherum account and Retik Meta mask wallet was drained. Lucky Retik only allowed 5% a week or they would have gotten all my tokens. How do I get my Retik tokens with my Meta Mask wallet attached to the Retik site. Retik will not show your tokens with any other wallets but the one you bought Retik with and that was my Meta Mask wallet. I tried attaching my CoinBase wallet and Retik would not show my tokens. Should I shutdown the Meta Mask site and upload it again and put in my recovery code and then try to get my Retik tokens again? Please someone help.... Thanks!

Can see the answer here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/162661/seed-phrase-compromised-erc20-nft-remaining-what-are-the-options, though the amount may not be enough to qualify for rescue from flashbots white hats. In which case you could need to spend a fair bit of time learning enough to do the whole thing atomically from a new account and set up some way to do it on each unlock.

Same happened to me. Woke up a couple of days ago to find someone had claimed 144000 Retik in 4No Transactions and immediately withdrew them. Going have to be quick at next claim to claim and export to different more secure wallet.

This question is similar to: I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum or Uniswap. What to do?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Retik is a scam. Same happened to me - they drained my wallet twice on both retik distributions

This has been flagged as low quality. Could you provide evidence of the scam?
If there are fake admins in the discord coercing keys from people you should report that specifically, especially if have screenshots from DM's. If a fishing attack, then may also be able to find the evidence by combing through your browser history, while cross referencing against the timestamps of the wallet being drained.
